# IPv6 equivalent of ETH_P_ARP

Tags: network-programming, ipv6

To determine if an IPv4 gateway is alive or not programatically, raw packet socket with ETH_P_ARP as the protocol, can be used as follows:

```
int fd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_ARP);
```

I'm looking for an IPv6 equivalent of ETH_P_ARP to use to ping an IPv6 gateway along similar lines. What are the other options in which this can be achieved programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: In IPv6 there is no ARP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was wondering if there's a way to use the packet sockets to ping an IPv6 gateway programmatically. Or any other recommended ways to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using wireshark, the protocol on a ND solicitation and on advertisement is just 0x86DD, and in if_ether.h that is assigned to ETH_P_IPV6.